# Hover/Dwell - How to

Tags: php

I have an application in PHP which displays sizable html "hover" blocks (title="hover text").
I would love to be able to format these blocks. Someone told me I could do that with Ajax, but I haven't been able to figure out how. If someone could just point me to a tutorial that addresses this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you only would like to change style of text you hover by mouse pointer, there is not needed to use ajax. There you may use pseudo-class :hover on element you need to re-style. Just simple write in any of your css files (for example) `a:hover{font-weight: bold;}`.

But this may be done also by JavaScript, pure or jQuery or so. Just write (with jQuery)

```
var MenuID_Mouseleave = function(){
    $('ul#'+ID).parent().css('background-image', 'none');
    };

var MenuID_Mouseenter = function(){
    $('ul#'+ID).parent().css('background-image', 'url(Grafika_Motiv/Pozadi_Tmave.png)');
    };
```

and

```
$('li#'+ID).bind('mouseleave', MenuID_Mouseleave );
```

where the first and the second part will define what will happen if you hovers element - and the third part will attach that action on hover of that element.

Also you would change text in hovered element without ajax - if you have written it somewhere, where it is not displayed in default.

But really, your question is not full. So, hard to help you more.